# C++ Program Boolean? Error

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a program that reads student IDs and grades from a file, with 3 functions:

- `getResults`: this function reads from the file and counts how many failed (if score < 55) calculates the average and returns the number of students.
- `display`: displays everything to the screen
- `isF`: checks whether the score is less than 55 and returns true if it is. *(In other words, if the student failed it will return true.)*

My program is working fine up to the checking how many failed. I'm almost certain its a logical error but I can't figure out where. The number of failed students is not being calculated correctly. I keep getting 1 when it is supposed to be 2 as per the sample file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int getResults(ifstream &input, int &failed, double &average);
bool isF(int score);
void display(int num_students, double average, int num_failed);

int main() {
    int numfailed, numOfStudents;
    double avg;
    ifstream in_stream("grades.txt");

    numOfStudents = getResults(in_stream, numfailed, avg);
    display(numOfStudents, avg, numfailed);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int getResults(ifstream &input, int &failed, double &average) {
    int studentID, studentGrade, total = 0, numberOfStudents = 0;

    while (input >> studentID >> studentGrade) {
        total = total + studentGrade;
        numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents + 1;
        failed = isF(studentGrade);
    }
    average = total / numberOfStudents;
    return numberOfStudents;
}

bool isF(int score) {
    if (score < 55)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void display(int num_students, double average, int num_failed) {
    cout << "Number of Students: " << num_students << endl;
    cout << "Class Average: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Number of students failed: " << num_failed << endl;
}
```

My sample file is as follows:

```
- 333 95
- 123 40
- 111 88
- 121 70
- 110 55
- 909 45
```

Sample output:

> Number of students: 6
>
> Class Average: 65
>
> Number of students failed: 2

The output I'm getting is exactly the same except that I get 1 student failed.

Comment: *My question is as follows, my program is working fine up to the checking how many failed. I'm almost certain its a logical error but I can't figure out where.* What is your question?

Comment: You need to accumulate the failures.

Comment: You can replace `if (score < 55)
        return true;
    else
        return false;` with `return (score < 55);`. But you aren't counting failures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First initialise your `numfailed` to `0` (thanks @ Peter), then change this:

```
failed = isF(studentGrade);
```

To this:

```
failed += isF(studentGrade);
```

Or this:

```
 failed += isF(studentGrade) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: `numFailed` needs to be initialised to zero in `main()`.   It is uninitialised - and not initialised to zero unless you explicitly do that..

Comment: Get in the habit of initializing your variable in general (at least for C/C++).

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks Chnossos and Peter!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to change. First initialize failed in your function to zero and then modify to add the count of failures. Here is the modified function:

```
int getResults(ifstream &input, int &failed, double &average)
{
    int studentID, studentGrade, total = 0, numberOfStudents = 0;
    failed = 0;

    while (input >> studentID >> studentGrade)
    {
        total = total + studentGrade;
        numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents + 1;
        failed += isF(studentGrade); //this ensures that every time a student fails, it is added
    }
    average = total / numberOfStudents;
    return numberOfStudents;

}
```